# Calculating expected travel time from set of polylines in iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, maps, mapkit, polyline

I have a set of polylines defining a route. Is there some way that I can use mapkit to calculate the expected travel time along this route? If not in MapKit, then in Google Maps or any other maps api?

Comment: It has to be from the set of polylines? So you can't just use the expected time from the source to the destination?

Comment: Oh, you have a set of polylines defining a route... Do you also have an MKRoute object containing those polylines?

Comment: Well I can make one probably but how would I get the expected travel time of that route? I can't create an MKDirectionsRequest object from an MKRoute object

Comment: `MKRoute` has an `expectedTravelTime` property.

Comment: Right but only if you get the MKRoute object from an MKDirectionsRequest call

Comment: That's why I originally asked whether your polylines come from a fetched MKRoute. How are these polylines being created? And are there multiple polylines? Your best bet is to either get the source and destination of each individual polyline, perform the MKDirectionsRequest (which is absolutely necessary to get expected travel time since the info obviously needs to be fetched), then add the expected travel times; or to perform an MKDirectionsRequest with the overall source and destination then find the specific route containing your polylines.

Comment: yeah that would work but i would assume apple would throttle the requests after you perform a certain amount in a certain timeperiod? I have around 30 points in each route, so i would have to perform 29 different MKDirectionsRequests

Answer (score 0):

```
 let sourcePlaceMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: fromCoordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
        let destPlaceMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: toCoordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
        let from = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlaceMark)
        let to = MKMapItem(placemark: destPlaceMark)

        print("caculateDirections ")

        let request = MKDirectionsRequest()
        request.source = from
        request.destination = to
        request.transportType = .Automobile

        let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler { (response, error) -> Void in
                if let response = response {
                    // Here you can get the routes and draw it on the map

                    let routeSeconds = response.routes.first!.expectedTravelTime
                    let routeDistance = response.routes.first!.distance
                 }
    }
```